# Javascript is undefined when project is put live

Tags: javascript

I have the following code, depending on the size of the screen will determine if they are re-directed to the mobile version of the site. Once on the mobile site if they choose to view the desktop version they're then redirected back to the desktop version and a cookie is created, that way they can continue to browse the desktop version without being re-directed again.

```
  $(function() {
        if (window.location.href.indexOf(".au") > -1) { 
            var oldURL = document.referrer;

            var t = getCookie("fromMobile");

            if (oldURL.indexOf("m.domain") > -1) {
                var date = new Date();
                var minutes = 30;
                date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
                document.cookie = "fromMobile=Yes; expires=" + date.toGMTString() + "; path=/";
            } else {
                if (t == "") {
                    if (screen.width <= 760) {
                        window.location = "http://m.domain.com.au/";
                    }
                }
            }

            function getCookie(cname) {
                var name = cname + "=";
                var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                    var c = ca[i];
                    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
                    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                }
                return "";
            }
        }

    });
```

When I'm running this on local/staging server it works as expected, I don't get any javascript errors, yet when pushed to live the error I get is on the following line

```
var t = getCookie("fromMobile");
```

It says getCookie is undefined

I'm uncertain why this works locally and on the staging server, I added alerts inside the getCookie when running locally/staging and I see the alerts....

Comment: @dsg - shortcut to `jQuery(document).ready(function() { ... })` is `$(function() { ... }`

Comment: Need more debuggin work - does console show any other errors? is the script being loaded correctly? does your live server has jQuery installed? (I'm assuming that's why the $ symbol?). If you're trying to make a self invoking function, seems like you got incorrect syntax. Possibly the funciton returns syntax error and therefore getcookie is never defined...

Comment: Code, as written, works fine and correctly (i.e. without errors). There's something not being shown.

Comment: @Yani I've just re-run the code mentioned above on the live server, using firebug the erorr I get is ReferenceError: getCookie is not defined
var t = getCookie("fromMobile");

Comment: @Adam the domain name is http://www.stainmaster.com.au/ when using firebug you will see the error, I'm currently using FireFox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the getCookie definition above "t" var, also you can prefer to use statement 
expressions when mixing functions, this will fix the problem with undefined.

Comment: so move the function getCookie above where I'm trying to call it you mean

Comment: yes, and it is always better to use function expressions when mixing functions, there can be unexpected behaviour when using function declarations

Comment: Yeah, I just found [this page](http://statichtml.com/2011/spidermonkey-function-hoisting.html) about how functions aren't hoisted inside `if` blocks in SpiderMonkey (Firefox's JS engine). Interestingly, that is actually consistent with the spec. The more you know!